# Sigmoid function in Neural Network in SAS Enterprise Miner

Tags: sas, neural-network, sigmoid

Is it possible to see the Sigmoid function (graphically) used internally when modelling Neural Network in SAS Enterprise Miner?

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: First, I'm curious what you mean . . . all sigmoids pretty much look the same (think S-shaped curve).  Second, EM's default is the hyperbolic tangent, not the sigmoid (which is used in logistic regression).

Comment: I don't know about hyperbolic tangent - need to check this. If I am not wrong, isn't Neural network apply sigmoid function at each neuron when computing the output? I am curious to know if we can see that shape in the output (graphical representation) of it to see how it is affected with changing input parameters.

Comment: . . I might suggest starting with my book "Data Mining Techniques for Marketing, Sales, and Customer Support".  The subject of neural networks is quite broad, and there are many good introductions to the subject.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Surely I will start your book. I would appreciate if you could, in the mean time, help me with this solution as well. Is there any node or SAS code to print the final function output graphically. Thank you!

Comment: @pinegulf . . . SAS EM provides the coefficients for each node in a neural network.  Plotting the curve has nothing to do with fitting the data -- it is just plotting the curve.  Fitting the data is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @pinegulf . . . As for your question, that is essentially logistic regression.